# Plotting the results of a system of equations

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, equation-solving

I believe this is a question of more list manipulation than plotting, but I hope you could help me. I solve numerically a system of equations of 3 variables, take only real solutions where one of the parameters is within the unit circle and evaluate its stability for different cost parameter C as

```
costValues = {};
solutionValues = {};
stabilityValues = {};
Do[
(*real steady state solutions where m is within the unit circle*)
ssOut = Select[NSolve[{x == xEq, p == pEq, m == mEq} /.{C -> costVal}, {x, p, m}], 
Element[{x, p, m} /. #, Reals] && 0 < ({x, p, m} /. #)[[3]] < 1 &];
(*calculate eigenvalues for the Jacobian for each solution*)
eigenValues = Table[N[Eigenvalues[jacobian /. {C -> costVal} /.solution]], {solution, ssOut}];
(*check how many eigenvalues are within the unit circle*)
stability = Table[Length[Cases[eigenValue, x_ /; -1 < Re[x] < 1]], {eigenValue,  eigenValues}];
(* append the results to the lists *)
AppendTo[costValues, costVal];
AppendTo[solutionValues, ssOut];
AppendTo[stabValues, stability];
, {costVal, 0, 1}]
```

My result lists look the  following

```
costVals= {0., 1};
solutionValues= {{}, {{x -> 28.8952, p -> 0.059159, m -> 0.010203}, {x -> -28.8946, 
p -> -0.0577157, m -> 0.010203}, {x -> 28.8886, p -> 0.0432996, 
m -> 0.010203}, {x -> -28.888, p -> -0.0418563, m -> 0.010203}}};
stabValues= {{}, {3, 2, 1, 1}};
```

Of course, there could be many more costVar values. The point is, that for each costVar value I could have a number of solutions with different stability values.

I would like to plot on separate diagrams different solution values x, p and m against the costValues and with a condition that if a stabValue is equal 2 the color should be green (stable) and if not then it should be red (unstable). So for example above, on horizontal axis I would like to have values 0 and 1 and on vertical axix for instance for variable x I would like to 0 points for costVal=0 and 4 points for costVal=1 where the second solution should be marked green and the other red. I spent a couple of days on that without a success, do you have any idea how to do that efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

To get the x values for example so you can plot them, you can do the following:

```
listx = {};

Table[
AppendTo[listx, x /. solutionValues[[2]][[i]]], {i, 1, 
Length[solutionValues[[2]]]}]
```

After that, you use Transpose to get whatever you want to plot against listx. You use If[] to get all your conditional statements on the length of costVals.

I hope it helps,
L.